# How can I install youtube-dl on BOSS linux?

Tags: software-installation, apt, python, youtube-dl

I try to install **youtube-dl** on **BOSS Linux**  by following commands.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
$ sudo pip install youtube-dl
$ sudo apt-get install $(apt-cache depends youtube-dl | grep Depends | sed "s/.*ends:\ //" | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Then following error occur.

[image: youtube-dl on BOSS linux]

**How can install *youtube-dl* on *BOSS Linux.***

Comment: You can download it directly from here: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=youtube-dl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install `pip` before you can use it  to install `youtube-dl`.

First install `pip`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then install `youtube-dl`:

```
 sudo pip install youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 0):

Using curl:

```
sudo curl https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2015.06.04.1/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

or using wget:

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2015.06.04.1/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

or using pip (if you haven't installed pip, run `sudo apt-get install python-pip`)

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

You can also use pip:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
```

*Source:youtube-dl official website*

I prefer downloading with wget. You don't need pip. But you will need python(which is already installed).

Bonus:

```
youtube-dl youtube_playlist_link --playlist-items 3,5,6,8 -g -f best' > list_url.txt
```

This piece of code tries to fetch the 3rd,5th,6th and 8th videos of the playlist and put those into **list_url.txt** ,which you can use later on with some download manager .